# Aggregating labels between timeseries

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have metrics that look like this:

```
myMetric{client="A",server="1",otherlabel="W"} 10
myMetric{client="A",server="2",otherlabel="X"} 21
myMetric{client="B",server="1",otherlabel="Y"} 32
myMetric{client="B",server="4",otherlabel="Z"} 43
```

I'm trying to find this data:

```
myMetric{client="A",servers="1,2"} 31
myMetric{client="B",servers="1,4"} 75
```

Is this even possible?  The data's there, I just can't figure out how to write the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible, however:

```
sum without(server, otherLabel)(myMetric)
```

will give you that with just the `client` label.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm currently doing a `sum(myMetric) by (client)`, but then I'm not able to correlate the servers.  :/